# Commands not working after adding message.delete() function to certain keywords

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot


client = discord.Client()
bot_prefix = "."
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix, case_insensitive=True)

ban_words = ['fuck',
              'shit']


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Shefkata e spremen")


async def on_message(ctx, message):
    if message.content.lower() in ban_words:
        await message.delete()


@client.command(pass_context=True, case_insensitive=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'pong {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')


@client.command(pass_context=True, case_insensitive=True)
async def shefe(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Sho sakash kopile")


@client.command(pass_context=True, case_insensitive=True)
async def zdravo(ctx):
    pozdravi = ["Zdravo",
                "Kaj si be",
                "Zdravo sinka"]
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(pozdravi)}')


@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['8ball'], case_insensitive=True)
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ["It is certain.",
                 "It is decidedly so.",
                 "Without a doubt."]
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')


@client.command(pass_context=True, case_insensitive=True)
async def dabs(ctx):
    broj = random.randint(0, 1000)
    if broj == 666:
        await ctx.send("JA PRONAJDE NAJRETKATA PORAKA\nIMASHE 0.1% SHANSA DA TI SE PADNI")
        await ctx.send("https://imgur.com/poI3bZl")
    broj = random.randint(0, 100)
    if broj == 69:
        await ctx.send("https://imgur.com/OOgEaLb")
    else:
        await ctx.send("https://imgur.com/RFlt0bz")


@client.command(pass_context=True, case_insensitive=True)
async def commands(ctx):
    await ctx.send(".ping\n.shefe\n.zdravo\n.8ball\n.dabs")

client.run('token')
```

The commands that used the bot prefix to run stopped working after adding a client event to delete messages containing certain keywords. I recently started coding so all help would be very appreciated. The discord.py documentation is kinda complicated so i cannot find what i am looking for. For more details please ask me in the comments.

Comment: I think you want `message.content.lower().split(' ')` in your `on_message` event. Also, does this mean your code ran fine as is without that `on_message` function? Can you try just removing it and seeing if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this:

```py
await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

Without this, none of your commands will work.

---

So, your event will look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    message = ctx.content.lower()
    for word in ban_words:
        if word in message:
            await ctx.delete()
            return

    await client.process_commands(ctx)
```

Also, you forgot to add `@client.event`. Without it, the `on_message()` function won't act as a listener.

Comment: @Don_Tofu please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `@client.event` decorator above the on_message function.
If you're checking for bad words you also need you use a for loop, the corrected code is:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx, message):
    message = message.content.lower()
    for word in ban_words:
        if word in message:
            await message.delete()
```